# Calling EventListener in HTML DOM using javascript for web element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, event-listener

In a web page I have a input box as below:

```
<input id="userId-inputEl" type="text" size="1" name="userId" placeholder="Enter Agent UserID..." style="width:100%;" class="x-form-field x-form-empty-field x-form-text" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false">
```

It looks like [![enter image description here][1]][1] as default when the page loads.

Now if I am trying to add value using

```
document.getElementById('userId-inputEl').value="test"
```

it writes the value in there and looks like [![enter image description here][2]][2]. After adding this value if I submit the form, it says the value is mandatory which means it has not accepted the value.

While typing manually, when I click on this box and type the value, it gets enabled and looks like this [![enter image description here][3]][3] and after submitting the form the value is accepted.

Now I have tried using

```
document.getElementById('userId-inputEl').click()
```

before passing the value, but it didn't work. After researching in google I found that there are some EventListeners attached with this element. They are as follows

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

I have tried using dispatchEvent with combination to blur, change, focus, input, keydown, mousedown, selectstart and textinput but of no use.

I'm new to eventlistener concept. How to achieve entering the value in the box using javascipt like it is done manually?

on opening the blur event from eventlistener tab in inspect window it looks like below:

[![enter image description here][5]][5]

I have no idea how to achieve this. Please help.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVVuQ.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5ezn.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgD0X.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP5zV.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEzM1.png

Comment: This is strange indeed. It seems like you are using some kind of validation plugin on the page, that does not react to `value` changes on the input element. What library are you using for form validation?

Comment: You **are** successfully entering a value in the box. The problem, whatever it is, is that whatever page this is on expects to see an event that makes it revalidate, and it's not seeing that event. I would have expected triiggering `input` or `blur` or `change` to make it revalidate. Please show how you triggered those events. And is this **your** page, or some page you're doing this on that you don't control?

Comment: There is a slim chance this isn't caused by some script and/or stylesheet that you do not disclose. There is nothing wrong with assigning `value`, you will need to cook this down to minimal verifiable example code, and only then will this question really be worthy of answering reliably. You most likely have overly complicated (and most often completely unnecessary) JavaScript form input validators, modifiers or other bonanza going on, judging by the behaviour you describe. And CSS rules to support said bonanza, which is why I suppose your text as assigned by a script is grey instead of black.

Comment: I'm trying to automate this page and I do not have any control on this page, whatever I can see is from inspecting window. after going into debugging mode I can see some scrips are running but those are from server side and hence encrypted without any function name like function (a,t,p) etc. I have used element.blur() or element.change() but none of them worked. Also tried element.dispatchEvent(event) with all the events I have mentioned, but of no use.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try this using jquery.
you have to download jquery or cnd
if you download jquery then :

```
<head>
    <title> My website</title>
<script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

or
if you cnd jquery then

```
<head>
        <title> My website</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
```

Next step :
**Html**

```
 <body >
<form id="AgentForm" name="AgentForm" > 
    <input id="userId-inputEl" type="text" size="1" name="userId" placeholder="Enter Agent UserID..." style="width:100%;" class="x-form-field x-form-empty-field x-form-text" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false">

    <button type="submit" name="submit"> Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
```

**js**

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#userId-inputEl').val("test") 
    $('#AgentForm').on('submit', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
       console.log($('#userId-inputEl').val());
      });
});
```